# Displaying a control over other controls in a grid in WPF

Tags: wpf, layout, overlay

I am developing a WPF application.
Main window's child controls are contained in a grid.
The bottom row contains a status bar.

The application must notify the user.
I want to programmatically display a notification in a user control in the bottom right corner of the main window.
I want the notification user control to be displayed over the status bar and the control in the above row.

How can I display a control over other controls contained in a grid ?
Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have solved my problem.
I have modified the main window's XAML markup.
I have declared the notification user control and the grid containing main window's child controls in the same cell of a new grid.

I have set some properties in the notification user control's opening tag :

- Grid.ZIndex="1"
- HorizontalAlignment="Right"
- VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
- Margin="0 0 20 20"

When the notification user control is visible :

- The notification user control is over the grid containing main window's child controls
- The notification user control is in the bottom right corner of the main window

Answer (score 10):

Grid has a property called ZIndex. Have a look at this example:

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" WindowTitle="ZIndex Sample">
  <Grid>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Rectangle Grid.Row="0" Grid.ZIndex="3" Fill="blue"/>
    <Rectangle Grid.Row="0" Grid.ZIndex="1" Fill="yellow"/>
    <Rectangle Grid.Row="0" Grid.ZIndex="2" Fill="green"/>

    <!-- Reverse the order to illustrate z-index property -->

    <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Grid.ZIndex="1" Fill="green"/>
    <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Grid.ZIndex="3" Fill="yellow"/>
    <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Grid.ZIndex="2" Fill="blue"/>

  </Grid>
```

If you don't specify ZIndex, the the children of a panel are rendered in the order they are specified (i.e. last one on top).

Comment: ZIndex is actually an attached property on Panel in WPF and also used by other overlapping layout panels like Canvas.

Comment: @JohnBowen thanks for your information. I will keep it in mind.

Comment: @Vishal I can not put the status bar and the notification user control on the same row. The notification user control's height will be greater than than the status bar's height. The notification user control must overlap the bottom row and be partially over the control above.

Answer (score 4):

Or, you can make use of [Popup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (always stays on top of other controls). And toggle it's IsOpen state when you want to show some updates.

```
<Popup IsOpen="True">
    <TextBlock Text="Important update!!" Background="White" Foreground="Black"/>
</Popup>
```

There are several ways you can stick popup to bottom-right position - Dockpanel, stackpanel (with right alignment), Grid. The sample for grid is below:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <!--Place any control here-->
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel x:Name="BottomRightPanel" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
        <Popup IsOpen="True" Placement="">
            <TextBlock Text="Important update!!" Background="White" Foreground="Black"></TextBlock>
        </Popup>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I have read MSDN documentation about Popup placement but I have not found how to place a Popup in the bottom-right corner of the main window. How can I do it ?

Comment: @user1139666 try to use `HorizontalAlignment="Right"` and `VerticalAlignment="Bottom"` on Popup.

Comment: Updated my answer above.

Comment: In my experience, `Popup` creates a separate Win32 window instead of an overlay in the current window, which isn't what I'm after because the Popup doesn't follow the main window around.

Answer (score 4):

Try this,

using Panel.ZIndex you can achieve this.

[image]

```
<Expander Name="expander_options" Header="Options"  Margin="330,10,0,182" Panel.ZIndex="1">
            <StackPanel Margin="10,4,0,0" Panel.ZIndex="2" Background="Aqua">
                <CheckBox Margin="4" Content="Option 1" />
                <CheckBox Margin="4" Content="Option 2" />
                <CheckBox Margin="4" Content="Option 3" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Expander>
```